# How to send mails using laravel with google workspace

Tags: laravel, gmail, google-workspace, mailing

I want to send mails using google workspace, like the wordpress SMTP mailer functionality, u create a app in google admin console and give the client_id and client_secret and then authenticate the app and thats it, all the emails are now sent via google workspace, how to do this for laravel?

i found many solutions like apppassword or username and password (not supported for long anymore) and google advises to use Oauth. i already have the authentication via laravel Socialite, now i have the access token but i dont know what to do next? anyone that can help me, or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options depending on how many messages you think you'll need to send. All of them require configuring the mail related environment variables as described in the Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/mail#configuration).

This [article](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?sjid=3924459355165966028-NA) from Google's support knowledge base may be helpful in deciding what option you wish to use.